# How to create a parameterized add-in for an excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros, add-in

I need to create an excel add-in that takes parameters of the upper and lower bound of two data sets.  I currently have a function written that performs the correct calculation for integration using the trapezoidal rule hardcoded in for a range with a lower bound of 4 and an upper bound of 13.

```
(=SUMPRODUCT(A5:A13-A4:A12;(B5:B13+B4:B12)/2)
```

I need to create a stand alone (possibly add-in) file that can be imported into any excel file and accept two parameters (upper and lower bound in place of the 4 and 13) to accomplish this function as simple as possible.

Would an add-in be the best way to go about this or is there some better way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2):

*my apologies; cannot comment yet as I don't have enough reputation*

**How would two parameters accomplish your function? I can't even get your formula running correctly?**

That said, you simply need to place your computation in a function in VBA, being sure to make it a `public` function, and then save that module, export it, and hand it over to whoever needs to use it. They *will* need to import the module into VBA, but after that they just need to call it from the formula bar, typing as you would a normal worksheet function like:

`=TrapezoidFunctionByCaseyHux(`

and then they will be asked to provide the parameter cells.

Hope this helps somehow

Answer (score 0):

To create UDF (user defined function) you can use also .Net through the 
[ExcelDna framework](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) .
So you can create your add-in and distribute it in your organization with an installer.

Answer (score 0):

Import a .bas file with this code into your Visual Basic editor for your excel worksheet

```
Option Explicit

Function Trapezoid(KnownXs As Variant, KnownYs As Variant) As Variant

    Dim i As Integer

    If Not TypeName(KnownXs) = "Range" Then
        Trapezoid = "X range is not valid"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Not TypeName(KnownYs) = "Range" Then
        Trapezoid = "Y range is not valid"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If KnownXs.Rows.Count <> KnownYs.Rows.Count Then
        Trapezoid = "Number of Xs <> Number of Ys"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Trapezoid = 0


    For i = 1 To KnownXs.Rows.Count - 1
        Trapezoid = Trapezoid + Abs(0.5 * (KnownXs.Cells(i + 1, 1) _
        - KnownXs.Cells(i, 1)) * (KnownYs.Cells(i, 1) + KnownYs.Cells(i + 1, 1)))
    Next i

End Function
```

You can then use your selection as parameters and add the .bas file to multiple workbooks